# How to add the <span> by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use the Javascript to add/remove the CSS/colour style to the html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689065/how-to-use-the-javascript-to-add-remove-the-css-colour-style-to-the-html-page)

I have a question on the HTML and javascript. I got the following paragrahe.

```
function add_span(){
     // ??
}

<input type="button" onclick="add_span()" value="add span"/>
<p> statement1, statement2, statement3 </p>
```

Is it possible to have the following result after the user

1. select the highlighted text by mouse
2. click the button

e.g.

1. highlight the 'statement1,'
2. click the button

Expected Result:

```
<input tupe="button" onclick="add_span()" value"add span"/>
<p> <span class="ABC">statement1,</span> statement2, statement3 </p>
```

##### Updated Code, but no work

```
// updated code in the add_span

    var selectedText;

    if (window.getSelection)
    {
        selectedText = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection) // FireFox
    {
        selectedText = document.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection)  // IE 6/7
    {
        selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    //create the DOM object
    var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
    // add the class to the 'spam'
    newSpan.setAttribute('class', 'ABC');
    document.getElementById('text').appendChild(newSpan);   
    var selectedTextNode = document.createTextNode(); 
    newSpan.appendChild(selectedTextNode);
```

Comment: I'm hoping they're just typos from writing the question, but you have misspelled `type`, and are also missing an `=` after `value` on your `input` element.

Comment: You [already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689065/how-to-use-the-javascript-to-add-remove-the-css-colour-style-to-the-html-page) this question.

Answer (score 5):

You can get selected text from @Pezhvak IMV's answer:

```
var selectedText;
if (window.getSelection)
{
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
}
else if (document.getSelection) // FireFox
{
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
}
else if (document.selection)  // IE 6/7
{
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
```

To add a element, you have to create a DOM node, set its attributes and add the element:

1. Create a DOM node:

   `var newSpan = document.createElement('span');`
2. Set the class

   `newSpan.setAttribute('class', 'ABC');`
3. Add the span to under the `<p>` (The `<p>` should have a id or some mechanism of identifying it:

   `<p id="text">`
4. Add the `<span>` to under the `<p>`

   `document.getElementById('text').appendChild(newSpan);`
5. And set the text

   `newSpan.innerHTML = selectedText;`

You can also use `createTextNode` (alternative for step 5)

```
var selectedTextNode = document.createTextNode(); 
newSpan.appendChild(selectedTextNode);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, and i still have some questions. After I add the code in the javascript, the <span> location is wrong, it add to the end of the <p>, not the suitable position. I have updated the code, would you mind to see one more?

Comment: @John, I am sorry, I did not first get the full context of the question. You want to highlight selected text, these should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240139/highlight-text-range-using-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584301/getselection-surroundcontents-across-multiple-tags/2584352#2584352, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582831/highlight-the-text-of-the-dom-range-element

Answer (score 2):

To answer part of you question:

```
function getSelText() {
    var txt = '';
     if (window.getSelection)
    {
        txt = window.getSelection();
             }
    else if (document.getSelection) // FireFox
    {
        txt = document.getSelection();
            }
    else if (document.selection)  // IE 6/7
    {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
    else return; document.aform.selectedtext.value =  txt; }
```